# Cherry-pick Commit from a different repo

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I was trying to cherrypick this commits

- https://github.com/AICP/frameworks_base/commit/59ebfb7146616e57c15469d7ea85c4362c2fab3c
- https://github.com/AICP/frameworks_base/commit/e24d0c250b4f80618f4b6064ad21d9c913890899

from https://github(dot)com/AICP/frameworks_base/ to 
https:// github(dot)com/Gopinaidu7/android_frameworks_base

I created a new branch with name master and switched to it.
I then did:

```
git cherry-pick 59ebfb7
```

and it got

```
fatal: bad revision '59ebfb7'
```

I also tried:

```
git cherry-pick 59ebfb7146616e57c15469d7ea85c4362c2fab3c
```

and got this error

```
fatal: bad object 59ebfb7146616e57c15469d7ea85c4362c2fab3c.
```

I was doing wrong and did tried to pick those commits since last night.
I was not able to do it, can someone point me with correct commands in sequence?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `i created a new branch with name master and switched to it`? Did you add a new remote for https://github.com/AICP/frameworks_base in your existing repository?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add that other repo as a remote first:

```
 git clone  https://github.com/Gopinaidu7/android_frameworks_base
 cd android_frameworks_base
 git remote add other https://github.com/AICP/frameworks_base
```

Then fetch:

```
 git fetch other
```

Now you can cherry-pick using the SHA1. And then push.

If the cherry-picked commit is a merged commit:

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 59ebfb7
```

Comment: @Gopinaidu you used the old url ending with a slash (/). As I said, I edited the answer. Plus, you need to do so in another brand new empty folder: say `~/test`, and don't forget the `cd ~/test/android_frameworks_base` after the `git clone` part: you need to be in the cloned repo for the other git commands.

Comment: @Gopinaidu Look at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41413383/revisions to see what I have removed

Comment: sorry , i forgot to change the directory and above comment is a mistake ..

Comment: Here is the error :

gopinaidunani@gopinaidu:~/framework/android_frameworks_base$ git cherry-pick 59ebfb7146616e57c15469d7ea85c4362c2fab3c
error: Commit 59ebfb7146616e57c15469d7ea85c4362c2fab3c is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
gopinaidunani@gopinaidu:~/framework/android_frameworks_base$

Comment: @Gopinaidu you should really try and cherry-pick a regular commit, not a merge commit. But if you must: `git cherry-pick -m 1 59ebfb7`

Comment: Thanks bro , u saved my day

Comment: @Gopinaidu You are most welcome. I have edited the answer to include the `-m 1` syntax for cherry-picking a merge commit. That will help others.

Comment: Yes , even that saved my time too .Thanks alot u solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new branch, just clone the target branch as suggested by @Vonc, and then run this command:

```
git checkout target_branch
git fetch https://github.com/AICP/frameworks_base && git cherry-pick 59ebfb7
```

Comment: this should be the answer to be found everywhere to cherry-pick without having to add a remote. So useful!! Locally, I do
`git fetch /another_build_dir/ && git cherry-pick <commit-it>`

Answer (score 1):

'bad revision' message comes whenever you are trying to cherry-pick a commit and you don't have that remote branch locally.

**Solution**

```
git fetch origin <remote_committed_branch>
git cherry-pick <commit-id>
```